# Does the space of positive signed measures have an interior

Tags: probability, measure-theory, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $\mathbf{X}$ be a compact interval on the real line with $B(\mathbf{X})$ representing the Borel algebra of $\bf{X}$. Let $M(\mathbf{X})$ be the space of finite signed measures, and let $\Vert\cdot\Vert$ be the total variation norm on $M(\mathbf{X})$.

Does the cone of non-negative measures contain an interior point? Specifically,
does there exist a measure $m\in M(\mathbf{X})$ and a constant $\epsilon>0$ such that for all $X\in B(\mathbf{X})$

1. $m(X)\geq 0$, and
2. $\tilde m(X)\geq 0$ for all $\tilde m\in M(X)$ with $\|\tilde m-m\|<\epsilon$?

**Some context to my question**

I am considering the following optimization problem:
$$
\inf_{y\in C}f(y) \hspace{1em} s.t. \hspace{.3em} g(y)\leq 0,
$$

where $C$ is a closed and convex subset of a vector space $Y$, and
$f:Y\to \mathbb{R}$ and $g:Y\to M(\mathbf{X})$ are continuous and convex functionals.

It is possible to address such an optimization problem by formulating a Lagrangian (for example, Luenberger's book *Optimization by Vector Space Methods,* Chapters 8 and 9). However, one of the conditions to guarantee the existence of Lagrange multipliers is that the feasible set $\{y\in C: g(y)\leq 0\}$ has a non-empty interior. However, this is not possible if the cone of positive (or negative) finite signed measures on $(\mathbf{X}, B(\mathbf{X}))$ has an empty interior.

Comment: Total variation norm requires finite measures.

Comment: Just edited the question. Thanks!

Comment: There exists $x_0$ with $m(\{x_0\})=0$; take $\tilde m=m-\frac {\epsilon } 2 \delta_{x_0}$. [I am assuming that non-negative measure means $m(E)\geq 0$ for al $E$  Borel , not just for $E=X$].

Comment: Thank you! This was my intuition as well, that there are Borel sets with arbitrarily small measure under $m$ that adding a bit of negative mass would move us out of the non-negative cone. Your argument makes it very clear.